# Stop and continue thread when button is clicked

Tags: multithreading

Hello) Can you please help me I need to make a thread sleep with pressing the button and continue this thread by pressing button1. I deal with WPF and when i call WaitOne()  method in button1_click event my form becomes freezed and i can't click any button. here's example of my code:

```
AutoResetEvent objAuto = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (thread != null)

        {

            objAuto.Set();
        }
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(zoo.FeedAnimals));
            thread.Start();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        objAuto.WaitOne();
    }
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: Please state what language you are using. It looks like C# to me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it freezes is because you call `WaitOne` on the UI thread. You probably want something along the lines

```
AutoResetEvent objAuto = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(zoo.FeedAnimals));
    thread.Start();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    if (thread != null)
    {
        objAuto.Set(); // this is in the main UI thread
    }       
}

public void FeedAnimals()
{   
    ...
    objAuto.WaitOne(); // this blocks your other thread
    ...
}
```